# How to check for subscription.ready() in a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, subscription

This is a very basic example how I get the data from the mongoDB to my meteor/react application.

Now I would like to show a loading icon while the data is getting loaded. Therefore I need to use something like `subscription.ready()` but where should I put this?

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data'

import Example from '../components/example.jsx'
import ExampleCollection from '/imports/api/collection.js'

export default createContainer((props) => {
    const   id = props.params.id,
            subscription = Meteor.subscribe('anything', id)
            data = ExampleCollection.find({ parent: id }).fetch()

    return { data: data }
}, Example)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do it like this:

```
    render() {
        if (this.props.isLoading) {
            return null; // or show loading icon
        }

        return (
            // stuff
        );
    }


export default createContainer((props) => {
    const   id = props.params.id;
    let subscription = Meteor.subscribe('anything', id);
    let data = ExampleCollection.find({ parent: id }).fetch();
    let isLoading = !subscription.ready();

    return {data, isLoading};
}, Example);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be better to try to load the data from the collection after the subscription is ready? That would ensure that all the data would be available when fetching.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might still be looking for this type of functionality, I think this might be a little bit better way to do this. Also note that currently createContainer is deprecated and changed to withTracker.

```
export default withTracker((props) => {
    let isLoading = true;
    let data = [];

    const id = props.params.id;
    const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('anything', id);
    if (subscription.ready()) {
        isLoading = false;
        data = ExampleCollection.find({ parent: id }).fetch();
    }

    return {data, isLoading};
}, Example);
```

This is Zim's answer refactored a little.